# Access variable inside a module's function

Tags: python-3.x

I have `common/auth.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess


def process_token():
    global TOKEN
    TOKEN = subprocess.Popen("auth-token",
                             shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             universal_newlines=True)
```

I also have `script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import common.auth

token = TOKEN.stdout.read()
headers = {'Authorization': "{token}"}
```

Why can't I use the variable from my python module? I get the error: `Undefined variable 'TOKEN'`

Comment: First of all, you would have to use `common.auth.TOKEN`. Secondly, I don't think the variable exists unless you call `process_token` once.

Comment: I've tried it with both 

```
from common.auth import process_token

process_token()

token = common.auth.TOKEN.stdout.read()
```

AND

```
import common.auth

process_token()

token = common.auth.TOKEN.stdout.read()
```

with no luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what exactly you have tried and include the complete error traceback you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TOKEN` is not defined until `process_token` gets called. Anyway `global` variables are a bad idea most of the time, avoid them until you really know what you are doing. A much better design here would be, for `common/auth.py`

```python
import subprocess

def process_token():
    return subprocess.Popen(
        "auth-token", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True
    )
```

and `script.py`

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import common.auth

token = common.auth.process_token()
headers = {'Authorization': "{token}"}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was close.